# Flutter: Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle Resources"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, info.plist

After upgrading flutter to flutter 1.22.4. I am getting the below error while building the Xcode Project.

> Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The
> Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle
> Resources".

Already tried the below options:

- Flutter clean and run.
- Removed derived data, clean project, and rebuild.
- - rm -Rf ios/Pods
  - rm ios/Podfile
  - rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
  - rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
  - rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
  - flutter run

After trying all the above options still getting the same error.

**Flutter doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at /Users/dhavalkansara/flutter 1.22.4
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (6 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dhavalkansara/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 202.8070

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 9D65DC5D-5DE8-485A-886F-FF26C0466391 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-2 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

- Project files structure:

[image]

- Info.plist location in build setting:

[image]

Also raised an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=2_bug.md&title=) for the same on Flutter Github.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Solution

---

Go to `Runner(target app) > Build Phases > Run Script` and update the run script with the one below.

```
 /bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build.
```

Also, verify that `Runner(target app) > Build Phases > Thin Binary` contains below scripts as suggested in [XCode 11.4 Support](http://Xcode%2011.4%20Support) by the flutter team.

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin
```

Comment: this helped me when i have created a new flutter project

Comment: FYI: I tried with Xcode 12.4 & only after clean the project, it successfully build. Note: in Runner(target app) > Build Phases > Thin Binary ->> "only single line that contains 'thin' present" i.e. "line that contains 'embed'" is not required/present.

Answer (score 38):

In Xcode Menu, choose "Product" > "Clean Build Folder".

Run the project again, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 steps to fix the issue after turn on your terminal window:

-You must navigate to your project folder that you already build with Flutter
-Then you will run as below :

1. $ flutter clean
2. $ flutter pub get

Then you build with the IOS simulator again. The issue will be solved.

**Reason:**
You have a clash between Xcode versions (old-new) in your app folder. You should clean the old one first and then rebuild it with the new one.

Answer (score 8):

I went with @Dhaval Kansara's suggestion and the error was still there. But after a clean build the problem went away.

Comment: This just happened to me after creating a new Flutter project. I went to Xcode first to verify that the script was correct (mentioned in other answer). The script was correct in Xcode, so a clean build just worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue.  Best solution is to simply *flutter clean* in the project folder

Answer (score 2):

`flutter clean` in the project folder solved it for me