# Unable to run flutter app on iOS emulator on Apple M1 processor

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

[image]

I tried running my app on a iOS emulator but I keep getting an error error: Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle Resources". I have the newest MacBook Pro M1 chip run Big Slur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle Resources"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434877/flutter-runner-app-info-plist-does-not-exist-the-flutter-thin-binary-build-p)

Answer (score -1):

It is good that you included that you have an M1 in your question.

However in this specific case, that is not the cause of your error (I also have an M1).

Please check this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435745/15443004

Before applying the changes there however, try a simple "flutter clean" in the project directory.